# Is the use of macros in order to provide typedefs for variadic template instantiations, a valid reason for their use?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, macros

I am writing a small C++ ECS framework. In order to speed up performance most framework types are variadic templates and require compile type info of the entity Components.
So ultimately The user has to do stuff like:

```
#include "./Components.hpp"
#include <framework/..>

class ExampleSystem : public fw::System<Component1, Component2, Component3....>
{
    ....
    bool registrationCondition(fw::Entity<Component1, Component2, Component3....> entity)
    {
        ....
    }

    ....

};
```

etc.

All template instantiations require the same template parameter pack.
As you can see however, this is ugly and tedious. I was wondering what is the general conscious of using a macro inside the library in order to provide typedefs.

For instance:

```
#include "./Components.hpp"
//used by the framework to provide convenient typedefs. Obviously should be guarded and put in another file
#define FW_COMPONENTS Component1, Component2, Component3, Component4, ....
#include <framework/..>

class ExampleSystem : public fw::System
{
    ....
    bool registrationCondition(fw::Entity entity)
    {
        ....
    }
    ....
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If another header includes `<framework>` before that one, you won't get what you're intending to get.

Comment: @Cornstalks I would put the macro in the Components.hpp header which includes all the Component headers. This makes sure that there won't be another wrong macro definition. It can also be protected with header guards. In any case I am asking about the general approach.

Comment: I'm not against macros in general as many C++ programmers are, but I think, this is not the place to use a macro. What I really consider ugly is to use macro definitions to communicate something to a header file. Headers should be independent of their inclusion context.

Comment: @cmaster Well this macro simply provides convenient typedefs. Since the template parameters are the same it just seems like too much work for the user to type all of the Components each time he needs any of the framework functionality.

Comment: Yes, but you are using it as an input argument to the header. If your header is included by several other headers, and not all of them use the same input parameter, the resulting behavior depends on the inclusion order. Which is more than just ugly. Imho, all headers should be written in such a way that you can just mindlessly include them from whichever other file that happens to need them. That's why we use include guards, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of Macro, you may do something like:

```
template <typename ...Ts> struct typedef_helper
{
    using system = fw::System<Ts...>;
    using entity = fw::Entity<Ts...>;
    // And so on.
};
```

Then

```
using my_typedef_helper = typedef_helper<Component1, Component2, Component3>;
using my_system = typename my_typedef_helper::system;
using my_entity = typename my_typedef_helper::entity;
// And so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need macros to avoid redundant type lists:

```
template <typename... Args>
class System
{
protected:
    typedef Entity<Args...> Entity_type;
};
```

Then, usage:

```
class ExampleSystem : public System<Component1, Component2, Component3>
{
    bool registrationCondition(Entity_type entity)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: I know. But imagine implementing say 20 components. It just feels burdensome to have to repeat them for every system, for the entity manager etc. Using the macro doesn't prevent the user from doing what you proposed it just also provides a few convenient typedefs.

Comment: Where is the repetition exactly?

Comment: The user creates many systems which are owned by the SystemManager. Entities are owned by the EntityManager.
Systems take entities and operate on them.

This requires all the systems, the EntityManager and the SystemManager to use the same template parameters.

Comment: Then have the SystemManager provide typedefs using the Components.  Though to be honest this framework sounds like overengineering in progress.  :)

Comment: It's an experiment mostly. Most C++ ECS frameworks use RTTI to map and retrieve Components. I am trying to implement this functionality at compile time. In any case the Systems still have to be defined separately. They kind of act like observers to the SystemManager which admittedly may not be clear from the naming.